# Datat is shown as System.Data.DataRowView when DataGrid table is exported to MS Excel

Tags: c#, wpf, office-interop, export-to-excel, com-interop

I have an export to Microsoft Excel button click event. The code that I have takes the `DataGrid` table and exports it to MS Excel.

The issue I am having is when the `DataGrid` is exported to Microsoft Excel the columns headers are correct but the data in the cells are showing as `System.Data.DataRowView`

[image]

Below is the code for my button click event:

```
    private void butn_ExportResults_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dt_ReportList.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            try
            {

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                xcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
               // Worksheet sheet1 = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];

                for (int i = 1; i < dt_ReportList.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                {
                    xcelApp.Cells[1, i] = dt_ReportList.Columns[i - 1].Header;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < dt_ReportList.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dt_ReportList.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        xcelApp.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dt_ReportList.Items[i].ToString();
                    }
                }
                xcelApp.Columns.AutoFit();
                xcelApp.Visible = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `DataTable`, so the row data type in the `DataGrid` will be [`DataRowView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowview?view=netcore-3.1). It contains the values for all columns for the current row. The problem is that you do not access these values but convert the `DataRowView` instance to `string` in this line:

```
xcelApp.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dt_ReportList.Items[i].ToString();
```

It does not override `ToString`, so the result will just be its type name. Instead you have to access the corresponding columns by index in the [`Row`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowview.row?view=netcore-3.1) property, e.g.:

```
xcelApp[i + 2, j + 1] = dataRowView.Row[j];
```

The `DataRowView` only changes in the outer loop, so we get and cast it there via pattern matching. The `if` statement ensures that the given item is a `DataRowView`, as the last row can be a blank row of type `NewItemPlaceholder` when [`CanUserAddRows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.canuseraddrows?view=netcore-3.1) is enabled on the `DataGrid` that needs to be skipped.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt_ReportList.Items.Count; i++)
{
   if (!(dt_ReportList.Items[i] is DataRowView dataRowView))
      continue;

   for (int j = 0; j < dt_ReportList.Columns.Count; j++)
   {
      xcelApp[i + 2, j + 1] = dataRowView.Row[j];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
dt_ReportList.Items[i].ToString();
```

You are referencing the row, the entire row.  This is your basic problem here and why you get a datarowview.

You want the column value in that row.

I think you can reference that using the column index.

Hence try:

```
dt_ReportList.Items[i][j].ToString();
```